# Using google load balancer in google compute engine in combination with google app engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine

I want to ask the community for feedback on my plan to address the following issue

**The issue**

When my project first starts as a google app engine, I have assigned `www.mycompany.com` as the custom domain of the production instance of my GAE app.

As the project grows, we deployed a wordpress powered managed VM in google compute to host blog and other marketing artefacts. The domain name of the wp site is `about.mycompany.com`

It causes a lot of confusion to users because `www.mycompany.com/home` will reach the web app, but `www.mycompany.com` redirects users to `about.mycompany.com`. Once they reached `about.mycompany.com`, they have trouble to get back to `www.mycompany.com/home`

This behaviour of `www.mycompany.com` is controlled by the yaml file of the google app engine project.

**Desired outcome**

The subdomain 'blog' should be eliminated

`www.mycompany.com/` -> blog/marking site

`www.mycompany.com/home` -> web app

**My proposed solution**

1. Set up a google load balancer to do url mapping
2. The load balance redirects '/' to the wordpress VM instance
3. The load balance redirects '/home' to the app engine server which will be moved to app.mycompany.com

Because google load balancer can only redirect to either managed or unmanaged instances within the google compute project, in order to achieve point 3 I will create an instance group of webservers (could be a `lighttpd`) whose sole responsibility is to redirect all incoming url to the app engine server

[image]

Is this feasible? Is there any catch?

Comment: This question seems more appropriate to the [App Engine Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine) and will likely be closed here.  I recommended posting your question there.  Food for thought, if you really **must** have all services under one domain/subdomain, I might consider deploying a WordPress docker image as a custom runtime App Engine service and using an external Cloud SQL instance for all the data.  This way, WP instances can replicate, data is consolidated and you can use dispatch rules to direct to each service.  I look forward to that Groups thread!

Comment: If you've opened a discussion thread on the Google Group, feel free to share a link to it here so that others can follow it through and see what others in the community recommend as a best practice.

Comment: @AnthonyKong Were you able to get this setup working? If so, Please post a self-answer, so to help the community having similar set up and problem.

Comment: @NaviAujla No, still haven't figured it out

Comment: @AnthonyKong Did you test with you proposed solution? If so, what problems did you encounter? Moreover, I would like you to check out [Google container engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/) which seems be one of the good solution for your deployment which can scale as well.